# function for searching web via terminal/aiml

Tags: python-3.x, bash, search, artificial-intelligence, aiml

"I am trying to make a bash function that will websearch and show result using aiml pattern on terminal. currently I can launch diffrent websites  from my code but I can't search results  . for example I want to say(write a command) "google(look for) answer to life and the pattern should Create a new window in existing browser session and show the result for answer to life from the web " is there a way to make it work ? I already tried urlib to fetch data from the web but it's not working .thanks
here is my aiml pattern

```
        <pattern>OPEN GOOGLE</pattern>
        <template>
             <random>
               <li>Sure thing! </li>
               <li>Right away, ! </li>
               <li>On it! </li>
            </random>
            <system> open -a "Google Chrome" http://GOOGLE.com</system>
        </template>
    </category>


    <category>
        <pattern>GOOGLE *</pattern>
        <template>
             <random>
               <li>Sure thing! </li>
               <li>Right away,! </li>
               <li>On it! </li>
            </random>
            <system> open -a "Google Chrome" http://GOOGLE.com/search?q=<star/>"</system>
        </template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>SEARCH FOR * ON GOOGLE></pattern>
        <template>
             <srai>GOOGLE <star/></srai>
        </template>
    </category>

    <category>
        <pattern>SEARCH GOOGLE FOR *</pattern>
        <template>
             <srai>YOUTUBE <star/></srai>
        </template>
    </category>
</aiml>
```

Comment: I feel like it might make the most sense to use Googles Custom Search API to interact with Google. Then there is no need to bring command line into the mix. Hit the API and get JSON back, parse it and build your AIML.

Comment: I thought there would be simple way other than that , thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the <link> tag.

```
<category>
    <pattern>SEARCH GOOGLE FOR *</pattern>
    <template>
        <link>
            <text>
                <random>
                    <li>Sure thing! </li>
                    <li>Right away, sir! </li>
                    <li>On it! </li>
                </random>
            </text>
            <url>http://GOOGLE.com/search?q=<star/></url>
        </link>
    </template>
</category>
```

You can also use Google's "I'm feeling lucky" ability to automatically open the first website it finds.

```
<category>
    <pattern>SEARCH GOOGLE FOR *</pattern>
    <template>
        <link>
            <text>
                <random>
                    <li>Sure thing! </li>
                    <li>Right away, sir! </li>
                    <li>On it! </li>
                </random>
            </text>
            <url>http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q=<star/>&amp;btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&amp;meta=</url>
        </link>
    </template>
</category>
```